# QuartusII 14.1.0 Debian Linux crash

Tags: linux, debian, intel-fpga, quartus

I can't use Quartus 14.1.0 with Linux Debian (wheezy and Jessie) on my 64 bits computer.

If I launch it on console I've got this message :

```
user@fpgaformation:/opt/altera/14.1/quartus/bin$ ./quartus
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 743: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

And the GUI is launched correctly.
But, after some minutes of using it, quartus disappear suddenly without message on terminal but with an altera problem-window.
In this window, we can get the following report :

```
Problem Details
Error:

*** Fatal Error: Segment Violation at (nil)
Module: quartus
Stack Trace:
    0x68cd4: fwrite + 0x34 (c.so.6)
    0x1205b: showit + 0x5b (curl.so.4)
    0x12388: Curl_debug + 0xe8 (curl.so.4)
    0x125ff: Curl_failf + 0xdf (curl.so.4)
     0x910f: Curl_resolv_timeout + 0x12f (curl.so.4)


End-trace


Executable: quartus
Comment:
None

System Information
Platform: linux64
OS name: Debian GNU/Linux
OS version: 7

Quartus II Information
Address bits: 64
Version: 14.1.0
Build: 186
Edition: Web Edition
```

I use also QuartusII 14.0.0 which work well on the same computer.

I know that Altera does'nt support Debian officially (only RedHat) but if somebody has a clue ?

Comment: I would suggest posting your question on an Altera support forum or opening a service request ticket with them (they are usually quick to respond).

Comment: Yes, I already asked Altera support. But I'm not sure there will respond me because I don't use RedHat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in Altera. They provided me a patch to correct it :

```
quartusii-14.1-0.19-linux.run
```

The patch can be found on altera support website :
[rd01272015_37](http://www.altera.com/support/kdb/solutions/rd01272015_37.html)

I applied it and quartus work well now. I think they will publish this correction soon.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug is back in 15.0 and 15.0.2.
#facepalm

Comment: @Gord-wait : Have you asked altera for a patch ?