# How do I fix this error that quartus 14.1 web edition on linux throws after a few minutes of use?

Tags: fpga, archlinux, quartus

I'm using quartus 14.1 web edition on linux but everytime I launch it, after a few minutes I get this error. I tried to search how to fix it but I went into a dead end. So anyone knows how do I fix this?

```
*** Fatal Error: Segment Violation at 0x7f672b52728a
Module: quartus
Stack Trace:
    0x214ed: addbyter + 0xd (curl.so.4)
    0x21829: dprintf_formatf + 0x159 (curl.so.4)
    0x22a45: curl_mvsnprintf + 0x25 (curl.so.4)
    0x125be: Curl_failf + 0x9e (curl.so.4)
    0x910f: Curl_resolv_timeout + 0x12f (curl.so.4)
    0x113da5: ASN1_primitive_free + 0x95 (crypto.so.1.0.0)
    0x1140f5: ASN1_template_free + 0x305 (crypto.so.1.0.0)
    0x113e9f: ASN1_template_free + 0xaf (crypto.so.1.0.0)
    0x6ad6: rml::internal::Backend::coalescAndPutList(rml::internal::FreeBlock*, bool) + 0x156 (tbbmalloc.so.2)
    0x6e66: rml::internal::Backend::splitUnalignedBlock(rml::internal::FreeBlock*, int, unsigned long, bool) + 0x106 (tbbmalloc.so.2)
    0x7837: rml::internal::Backend::genericGetBlock(int, unsigned long, bool) + 0x187 (tbbmalloc.so.2)


End-trace


Executable: quartus
Comment:
None

System Information
Platform: linux64
OS name: Manjaro Linux
OS version: 

Quartus II Information
Address bits: 64
Version: 14.1.0
Build: 186
Edition: Web Edition
```

Comment: I think your can only put the test case to Intel but I am not sure you will get a solution as my experience is that big companies are not interested in small users or even medium users. They only want to talk to multi-million dollar users these days. p.s. As last resort you can try to bisect your code until the error goes away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QuartusII 14.1.0 Debian Linux crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538645/quartusii-14-1-0-debian-linux-crash). See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd01272015_37.html

Comment: Can you show the warnings/critical warnings you see in the log before it crashes?

Comment: @user1155120 this fix worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1155120 this was a know bug from altera and to fix it I needed to install this [patch](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd01272015_37.html) that fixed the issue

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate after finding the previous question and matching the stack trace on the Intel site. Unfortunately there isn't a lot of moderation going on lately, this question would normally be closed as a duplicate.